# how to convert .xml file to .trg file with same XML file structure

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML code in PowerShell script. The code is executing fine and I get the XML structure in `myTest.xml` output file which is correct.  I would need to convert this `myTest.xml` output file to `.trg` (say `output.trg`) file with the same XML structure in the output.trg file. how to achieve this?

```bsh
$xmlsettings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
$xmlsettings.Indent = $true
$xmlsettings.IndentChars = "    "

$XmlWriter = [System.XML.XmlWriter]::Create("C:\myTest.xml", $xmlsettings) 

$xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()
$xmlWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href='style.xsl'")

$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Root") 
    $xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Test1","1")
    $xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Test2","2")
    $xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Test3","3")      
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() 

$xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument()
$xmlWriter.Flush()
$xmlWriter.Close()
```

Expected output file (`output.trg`):

```xml
<Root>
<Test1>1</Test1>
<Test2>2</Test2>
<Test3>3</Test3>
</Root>
```

Comment: `Copy-Item 'C:\myTest.xml' 'C:\output.trg'`

Comment: @Ansgar. Thanks! Yes Im aware of this Copy-Item code. But how to achieve using set-content in this line of my above Code: $XmlWriter = [System.XML.XmlWriter]::Create("C:\myTest.xml", $xmlsettings)

Comment: @MaheshMohan Why do you want to use an XmlWriter if you just want a copy of the file with a different extension?

Comment: You don't use `Set-Content` in that line. If you want the writer to create a different output file simply change the file name. With that said, allow me to suggest that you immerse yourself in a PowerShell tutorial first. Because your questions clearly indicate that you have no idea what you (or any of your code) are doing.

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen I'm learning PowerShell. As the expected output is similar like XML structure, so I thought i need to use the XmlWriter to achieve that output. Any other way you would like to recommend, pls let me know.

Comment: @MaheshMohan Ansgar already recommended a much simpler solution - just call `Copy-Item` and be done with it :)

Comment: cat "C:\myTest.xml" > "C:\output.trg"